# Saml2Login with Grails Spring Security Core

Tags: grails, spring-security-saml2

Able to redirect to IDP login page with compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-saml2-service-provider', version: '5.4.6' in grails application.

Unable to redirect to IDP login page by adding compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:4.0.3" dependency(Which is required to support db user authentication) along with spring-security-saml2-service-provider in grails application.

Could you please suggest on this

Comment: Sorry to hear you are having trouble. More information will be needed, though. What is the request and response that aren't working and what would you expect them to be? Also, you might post a minimal sample to GitHub so that folks can more clearly see what you mean.

Comment: Above issue is resolved by creating a new groovy file CustomSaml2WebSsoAuthenticationRequestFilter which extends Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationRequestFilter and registered in resource.groovy. Now able to redirect to IDP login page.